# Faulty altitude point between contours

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, line, contour, altitude

I have point(picket?) between 2 contour lines with even number altitudes. 
Now i got these new 5 meters steps contour in between. As you see, this point between red lines was OK, but now that this 175 apeared it's wrong.
I want to find faulty points between contours.
I would love to avoid creating new polygons from contour lines, because there's alot of features. Any ideas?[image: Faulty altitude point between contours.]

Comment: How were your contours created?

Comment: DEM and line generalization.

Comment: How does these seemingly wrong values compare to the value in your DEM? Use `Extract values to point` if you want to check many of them

Comment: In these conditions I cant use DEM. Solution has to come  from what I have: contour lines and points

Comment: Maybe a little off topic, but in that case, how do you know that these values really are wrong and the difference isn't just a generalization error from the contour creation?

Comment: It may be an error, but my job is to fish them.

Comment: Alright, while staying on topic, the one solution that comes to mind is to interpolate a new raster from your contours, given that polygon creation isn't favourable. Then compare the raster values with the previously mentioned tool and have a closer look at those which differ more than 5 meters. It's not gonna be perfect, but it'll get you somewhere. I suppose a vector only solution is possible with finding closest polylines (maybe with directions), but it'll require non-trivial programming and there will likely still be fringe cases that you'll have trouble solving.